# Combining Arrays while merging the values with the same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with same amount of values. I need to combine them ( array1 value to key, array2 value as value) without losing the values of the second array due to duplicate key. when I use combine_array() as expected it just gets the last value of the second array with the same key.

```
Array
    (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
 
)

Array
    (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Desired result

```
Array
    (
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array(
        [0]=>2
        [1]=>3
        )
    [3] => 2
 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are way better solutions than this, but it does the job for now. I would appreciate if someone can send a better written solution.

```
$combined = array();
$tempAr = array();
$firstMatch = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $index => $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $combined)) {
        $tempAr[] = $array2[$index];
        $count++;
    } else {
        $totalCount = $count;
    }
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $firstMatch)) {
        $firstMatch[$key] = $array2[$index];
    }
    $output = array_slice($tempAr, $totalCount);
    $combined[$key] = $output;
}
$combined = array_merge_recursive($firstMatch, $combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will meet your request

```
$array1 = array("0"=>1,"1"=>2,"2"=>2,"3"=>3);
$array2 = array("0"=>1,"1"=>2,"2"=>3,"3"=>4);
$array = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
   if($value != $array2[$key]){
     $array[$key][] = $value;
     $array[$key][] = $array2[$key];
   }else{
     $array[$key] = $value;
   }
}
print_r($array);
```

The desired result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I need the first array's key combined with the second array's value.